# onOptionsItemSelected is never called

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu), and I'm writing a simple `Activity`.

...

**UPDATE**: After your tips I've edited my app, but the method `onOptionsItemSelected()` is still not called when I select an item from the popup menu. The popup menu is inflated when the user click on an item from the action bar.

The activity:

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
    ResourceState.OnResourceStateChangeListener {

...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Map.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        ...

        case R.id.menu_item_map_type:
            // Here I show the popup
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.menu_item_map_type));
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_popup, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();
            break;

        case R.id.menu_item_satellite:
            // here the method onOptionsItemSelected is not directly called
            break;

        case R.id.menu_item_street:
            // here the method onOptionsItemSelected is not directly called
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void callOnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

...
```

}

The primary menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_send"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_send"
          android:title="send"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_location"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_location_on"
          android:title="my position"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_map_type"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
          android:title="map view"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

The popup menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_satellite"
        android:title="satellite"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:onClick="callOnOptionsItemSelected"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_street"
        android:title="street"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:onClick="callOnOptionsItemSelected" />

</menu>
```

My temporary solution is defining the method `callOnOptionsItemSelected()`, wich calls the method `onOptionsItemSelected()`. By the way, I'd like to know what I'm missing.

(Another issue related to the popup is that the method `setChecked()` of the class `MenuItem`, is not working.)

Comment: Maybe the problem is because you don't check to see if the item is your button ( item.getItemId() == R.id.sat ) , then do item.setChecked(true), then return true.
The tutorial you've linked states that "When you successfully handle a menu item, return true. If you don't handle the menu item, you should call the superclass implementation of onOptionsItemSelected() (the default implementation returns false)." under "Handling Click Events".

Comment: @frenk I ran your test code and onOptionsItemSelected was getting called just fine. Do you happen to have a library that also uses Log.d? Maybe you imported the wrong Log.d and so it's not showing up in the console.

Comment: I've changed the code as you suggest, but nothing is changed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you add

```
android:id="@+id/layout_map_popup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in your  `menu.xml` file